# Retrieving only array objects with the selected conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm having quite a bit of trouble with aggregating only the specific array objects in my mongoDB express app. Here is the document structure:

```
[
  {
    name: "Object 3"
    components: [
      [
        { price: 121, timestamp: ISODate(...) },
        { price: 111, timestamp: ISODate(...) },
        ...
      ]
      [], [], [] // 4 components overall
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I basicly want to get all {price,timestamp} objects in an array where the price is, say, greater than 100 in a single component.
With just find() I have this, but as expected this just returns every Object which has a price field with greater than 100

```
// Searches every component[0] for objects with price > 100
db.collection(collection).find({
    'components.0.price': { $gte: 100 }
}).toArray(function (err, result) {
     if (err) throw err

     console.log(result)
})
```

Now I googled a bit and found some aggregation stuff with $filter, the problem is just my database is very big and my console actually times out because the process is out of memory. The thing is I have no idea if thats because I aggregate wrong or because of the big database. It didn't have problems with the above code which basically returns every Object (since every Object has so many requests everyone has one with > 100), so I suspect im using it wrong in the nested array:

```
db.collection(collection).aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            'components.0': {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$components.0',
                    as: 'component',
                    cond: { $gte: ['$$component.price', 200] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err

    console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: Can you try `input: { $slice: [ "$components", 1 ] }` ?

Comment: throws `MongoError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out` on `process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });` after some time

Comment: Not sure why you see time out error considering your server is running fine. Do you have access to shell ? Try `db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            'components': {
                $filter: {
                    input: { $slice: [ "$components", 1 ] },
                    as: 'component',
                    cond: { $gte: ['$$component.price', 200] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])` from mongo shell

Comment: in the console it works. strangely enough it aggregates everything, even stuff under 200. when I only scan 1 item with the code in my original question instead of all of them, it works but aggregates nothing, just an empty components array

Comment: Can I see your updated query ?

Comment: Same as in the question / your comment, I just deleted every other object https://pastebin.com/qLdaCYaM

Comment: `$slice` returns array of values. In your case values are array. So it returns array of arrays. Try `input: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$components", 0 ] } `. This will work as expected.

Comment: If your problem is just because of the big data as you stated, you can use the flag `allowDiskUse:true` in aggregation after the pipeline. May be it can help or get the cursor and iterate over that.

Comment: this works now, at least in console. in code I get the error `MongoError: BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 134217728 bytes, past the 64MB limit.`, even with allowDiskUse

Comment: Okey, I've read up on it a bit and it seems to be because aggregate returns only a single document which has the 64MB limit. in the mongo docs it seems like you can somehow specify it to return multiple cursors/documents instead of a single one, but I can't figure out how. Neither the docs nor google are really helping here